# Intel XDK + Cordova. Do you need authorization to access device microphone?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, intel-xdk, audiocontext

I am new to mobile app development. I made a web tuner using [audioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) to get the user pitch. It works just fine. I would like to translate this to android / ios. I am using intelXDK where I believe Cordova plugins can be imported. I can run the application on both emulators (ios and android) just fine. I can detect the audio as pretended. I can also get it working (with some problems on the screen resolution) when I test the app by pushing it to the server and run it from my android device. There, I Can also receive user sound input. However, when I debug the app on my cellphone I can't the user audio input... Do I need to, somehow, get the user authorization to use his microphone?

Comment: Please see my answer on your other question related to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41175381/6609803